# send batch processing to a file

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a file text.txt that gets parsed by the code below. The batch file works, but I want the output to write a new file (or modify the original, whichever is easier). Currently the output is displayed in the command window only.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^

%var1% 
%var2%

set "EOL=!LF!" & set "EOL2=!LF!"

for /F %%a in (test.txt) do (
   if %%a equ PROP-SUMMARY set "EOL=!LF!"
   set /P "=%%a!EOL!" < NUL
   set "EOL0=!EOL!" & set "EOL=!EOL2!" & set "EOL2=!EOL0!"
   if %%a equ PROP-VALUES set "EOL=,"
)
```

This is **test.txt**

```
4.12
0
1
1
21
PROP-VALUES
625
4.12
945
3.64
PROP-SUMMARY
400
400
Thickness
```

This is **new.txt**

```
4.12
0
1
1
21
PROP-VALUES
625,4.12
945,3.64
PROP-SUMMARY
400
400
Thickness
```

Comment: What is `%var1%` and `%var2%` for?

Comment: they are placeholders. If they're removed, script doesn't work.

Comment: You can remove them! You just need to make sure that `set LF=^` is followed by two empty lines, that is all...

Answer (score 0):

cmd.exe >> "%SystemDrive%/Users/%username%/Desktop/test.txt"

this will not overwrite test.txt but add to it.
to make it overwrite test.txt do

cmd.exe > "%SystemDrive%/Users/%username%/Desktop/test.txt"